# If I have two identical elements, one scaled to 2x, how scale down it's inner element and place it where it would be at 1x?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have two identical elements. The top one, I'm scaling to double the size and then centering over the normal-sized one. I want its inner element to then be scaled back down to normal size and placed exactly where the normal sized element's inner element is placed.

This seems to be impossible. There seems to be no logic in the scaling + translation of position.

How would I do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/0urdrvao/

HTML:

```
<div class="top">
  <div class="inner">
    Inner
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  <div class="inner">
    Inner
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.top,
.bottom
{
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 0;
}

.top
{
  position: fixed;
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transform: translate(-150px, -150px) scale(2);
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: 1;
}

.inner
{
  position: relative;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.top .inner
{
  /* This doesn't work */
  transform: translate(150px,150px) scale(.5);
  /* This also doesn't work (doing half)*/
  /*transform: translate(75px,75px) scale(.5);*/
  /* This also doesn't work (doing double)*/
  /*transform: translate(300px,300px) scale(.5);*/
  transoform-origin: 0 0 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: @JoshCrozier It doesn't work. Change the height of the viewport (drag the small window with the content in it) and you'll see it's no longer over it. (When I viewed it, it was not over it, so i assume you placed it for what the height was in your browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `top: 20vh` will be scaled times 2, the transform-origin should be `0 -20vh`.

When reverse a scale/translate you need to go *backwards* and start with scale and then the translate

```
.top{
  position: fixed;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translate(-150px, -150px) scale(2);
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: 1;
}

.top .inner{
  transform: scale(.5) translate(150px, 150px);
  transform-origin: 0 -20vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0urdrvao/3/)

Or one could do like this, setting origin to `0 0` and `transform: scale(.5) translate(150px,150px) translateY(-20vh);`

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0urdrvao/2/)

Comment: So, I'm scaling and then undoing the original top/left? I'm not 100% certain i understand why this works.

Comment: @DonRhummy When you scale times 2, the `top: 20vh` becomes `top: 40vh`, so you need to move that back, hence giving the origin `0 -20vh` ... and left is 0, so nothing happens there

Comment: @DonRhummy You could also set origin to `0 0` and use this `transform: scale(.5) translate(150px,150px) translateY(-20vh);` .... fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0urdrvao/2/

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!